# javascript single quote / double quote

Tags: javascript, html, string, events, quote

this is my original html codes:

```
<div>
    <img src="image/sample.jpg" onmouseover="showTitle('title')">
</div>
```

But I need it to be converted to javascript, for condition if {{IMAGE(z1)}} do exist, then var x, would be written out as html.

```
 <script>
    if ("{{IMAGE(z1)}}" != "") { var x = "<img src="image/sample.jpg" onmouseover='showTitle('title')'></div>"; 
    document.write(x); } 
 </script>
```

The image does show; however, it wont read/execute the related javascript functions.

HTML:

```
onmouseover="showTitle('title')"
```

Javascript variable double quote (failed):

```
var x = "onmouseover="showTitle('title')""
```

Javascript variable single quote (failed):

```
var x = "onmouseover='showTitle('title')'"
```

Do you know a workaround of this?  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why not avoid the whole problem by attaching the handler externally instead of inline?

Comment: And don't use `document.write()`

Comment: Escape all double and single quotes inside your js var with a backslash \

Comment: Why are you not using escape sequence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = "<img src=\"image/sample.jpg\" onmouseover=\"showTitle('title')\"></div>";
```

Comment: so whenever the html has double quote " i can replace it with \" inside my variable correct?

Comment: Basically... you use the backslash to "escape" special characters in JavaScript.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/2yfce773%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Note you are missing the starting `<div>` and you need to ensure to escape quotes. Try and use single quotes inside double quotes and vise-versa, only escape when you have to:

```
var x = "<div><img src='image/sample.jpg' onmouseover='showTitle(\"title\")'></div>";
```

When you want to place a double quote inside double quotes you need to escape the inside with `\"` the same applies to single quotes `\'`:

```
" \" " -- Double Quotes Escape
' \' ' -- Single Quotes Escape
```

Also note unless you are using a library that interprets `{{ .. }}`, this condition `"{{IMAGE(z1)}}" != ""` will always be true.

Comment: thank you for your detailed explanation. learning some terms i didnt know. Thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

Main error : change ,

```
 var x = "<img src="image/sample.jpg" onmouseover='showTitle('title')'></div>";
```

To

```
 var x = "<img src=\"image/sample.jpg\" onmouseover=\"showTitle('title')\"></div>";
```

By the way your method is actually bad.

I wonder if that `if` would work... I dont know much of js but i would say, leave that method.

Second, use jquery if possible .

U can simple do

```
$("#i").mouseover(function(){
showTitle('title'); });
```

Where `i` is the id of image